# Issue with VMNet8 and/or DNS configuration in VMWare Workstation 12

Tags: networking, dns, vmware, private-network

I set up a virtual private network by enabling VMNet8 in VMWare Workstation 12.5. The network entails an Active Directory domain controller (and DNS server role) installed with Windows Server 2012 R2. In addition, I have set up a SQL Server, an app server and a web server with Windows Server 2016.

**I am unable to ping from the AD/DNS server to other servers, but the other way works.**

All 4 servers have connectivity to the Internet, even though all of them have an exclamation mark superimposed over the network icon (in the taskbar).

I have assigned static IP addresses in succession, from `192.168.153.15` to `192.168.153.18`. Using Virtual Network Editor, I enabled a `Virtual Network Adapter VMNet8` with following properties:

- Type: `NAT`
- Subnet address of `192.168.153.0`
- Gateway IP is set by default to `192.168.153.2`

In the AD/DNS VM, following properties are set on the single network adapter:

- Static IP of `192.168.153.15`
- subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`
- Default gateway is `192.168.153.2`
- Preferred DNS server is `127.0.0.1` (loopback address)
- Computer belongs to `contoso.local` domain (established by AD setup)

In the other VMs, following properties are set on the single network adapter:

- Static IP of `192.168.153.16`, `192.168.153.17` and `192.168.153.18` (respectively)
- subnet mask is `255.255.255.0`
- Default gateway is `192.168.153.2`
- Preferred DNS server is `192.168.153.15` (IP of the AD/DNS server)
- Computer belongs to `contoso.local` domain (established by AD setup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewall rules on the other VMs prevented any traffic flowing in or out of them. Since this is only a playground, I turned off the firewall at the scope of the domain network on all of them. This immediately allowed all the VMs to communicate with one another.

I should set up inbound/outbound rules for the specific routes, in the real world.